# Save first row only in Entity Framework and windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

In a Windows forms application, I have 2 classes and I am using Entity Framework 6.

```
public class Sale
{
    public Sale()
    {
        SalesDetails = new List<SalesDetail>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int SaleId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal FinalTotal { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesDetail> SalesDetails { get; set; }
}

public class SalesDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int SaleDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Sale Sales { get; set; }
}
```

and my `DbContext` is:

```
public class MyStoreDbContext:DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<SalesDetail> SalesDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I try to save a list of `SalesDetail` to a `Sale` entity by looping the datagridview and item every time of although the salesdetails has list of row 
my code is

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBarcode.Text != "")
        {
            // prepare items data
            Sale newSale = new Sale();
            SalesDetail sl = new SalesDetail();

            for (int i = 0; i < grdItems.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sl.Quantity = int.Parse(grdItems.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString());
                sl.TotalPrice = decimal.Parse(grdItems.Rows[i].Cells["Value"].Value.ToString());
                sl.UnitPrice = decimal.Parse(grdItems.Rows[i].Cells["Price"].Value.ToString());
                sl.ProductId = getProductId(grdItems.Rows[i].Cells["BarCode"].Value.ToString());
                newSale.SalesDetails.Add(sl);
            }

            newSale.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            newSale.Total = decimal.Parse(txtTotal.Text);
            newSale.Discount = decimal.Parse(txtDiscount.Text);
            newSale.FinalTotal = decimal.Parse(txtFinalTotal.Text);

           _ctx.Sales.Add(newSale);
           _ctx.SaveChanges();

            items = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move `SalesDetail sl = new SalesDetail();` into the the loop

Comment: works fine thanks , :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `SalesDetail` object over and over again.

You need to create a new one for each row in the loop like this:

```
//...

Sale newSale = new Sale();

for (int i = 0; i < grdItems.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    SalesDetail sl = new SalesDetail();
    //...
}

//...
```